# Clarification on dispose method

Tags: c#

If I wrap in a class an object that has the dispose method I'll need to implement the dispose method in the class too?

For example I have a class which wraps an instance of `SQLiteConnection`, should I need to implement the dispose method to call the `SQLiteConnection` one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example I have a class which wraps an instance of SQLiteConnection, should I need to implement the dispose method to call the SQLiteConnection one?

Yes.

If you have `MySQLiteConnection` which makes/opens a `SQLiteConnection` it will not automatically dispose of that member on garbage collection. You need to explicitly mark your wrapper as `IDisposable` and call the member `SQLiteConnection::Dispose`.

If you're just *using* the `SQLiteConnection` in the class, or you have a reference to one (but don't open/own it), the Robert Harvey's answer is correct - just use it as you would anywhere else.

Comment: I would advise against storing disposables as members. It complicates things needlessly in many cases.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a class which wraps an instance of SQLiteConnection, should I need to implement the dispose method to call the SQLiteConnection one?

Nope.  Just wrap your SQLiteConnection instantiation in a `using` statement.

```
using (connection = new SQLiteConnection())
{
    // use `connection` here
    // ...
} // `connection` is disposed here.
```

Because `SQLiteConnection` implements [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), the `connection` object is automatically disposed when the `using` block goes out of scope (at the ending brace of the `using` statement).

If you are inheriting from `SQLiteConnection`, then inherit also from `IDisposable` and implement the `Dispose()` method, which will do any local cleanup that's needed in your descendant class and then call `Dispose()` on the parent `SQLiteConnection` class.

**Further Reading**
[Using Statement (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: But he says that he wants his class to *wrap* an IDisposable, he does not say that he wants his class to simply *use* an IDisposable.

Comment: @MikeNakis: Depends on whether you are using inheritance or composition.